# For $V=V(r)$, where $r^2=x^2_1+x^2_2+...+x^2_n$, $\sum_1^n\frac{∂^2V}{∂x_i^2}=\frac{∂^2V}{∂r^2}+αV_r$, then what is the value of α?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> **For $V=V(r)$, where $r^2=x^2_1+x^2_2+...+x^2_n$,
>   $\sum_1^n\frac{∂^2V}{∂x_i^2}=\frac{∂^2V}{∂r^2}+αV_r$, then the value
>   of α is**
>
> (A)$\frac{1}{r}$
>
> (B)$\frac{n}{r}$
>
> (C)$\frac{(n-1)}{r}$
>
> (D)$0$

I have computed
$\frac{∂V}{∂x_i}=\frac{∂V}{∂r}\frac{∂r}{∂x_i}=\frac{∂V}{∂r}\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{\sum_1^n x_i2}}$.

But,from here  i got puzzled  in calculating second derivative  of $V$ w.r.t $x_i$.

I've invested a great amount of time in this problem...I'll be thankful if someone come up with answer

Comment: I believe it's (C), because it fits with 2d and 3d cases (and 1d of course)

Comment: @Yuriy:Thanks for your response, but What is the analytic reasoning?Can you tell what is the expression for the second derivative for $V$ w.r.t $x_i$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember this topic very well. Don't use more than 3 dimensions

Comment: @YuriyS:Its ok.i appreciate your suggestion...thank you:--)